# The space [0,1] relativesed with usual topology is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Source: On Minimal Separation Axioms in Topological Spaces (2012)

- **Definition(Minimal Closed Set):** A proper nonempty closed subset $F$ of a topological space $X$ is said to be *minimal closed* if any
  closed set which is contained in $F$ is $\emptyset$ or $F$.

  **Definition(Minimal Completely Regular Space):** For every point $x\in X$ and each minimal closed set $F\subset X$ such that $x\not\in
     F$, there exist a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that
  $f(x)=0$ and $f(F)=\{1\}$.

  **Definition(Minimal c-regular Space):** For every point $x\in X$ and each minimal closed set $F\subset X$ such that $x\not\in F$, there
  exists open sets $U,V\subset X$ such that $x\in U$, $F\subset V$ and
  $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

**Theorem:** Every min-completely regular space is min c-regular space.

**Proof:** Let $X$ be a min-completely regular space. To prove $X$ is min c-regular space. Let $x\in X$ and $F$ be any minimal closed set in $X$ such that $x\not\in F$. Since $X$ is min-completely regular space, there exists a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(F)=\{1\}$. **Also, it is easy to see that the space $[0,1]$ with relativesed usual topology is Hausdorff space.** Hence, there exist open subsets $G,H\subset [0,1]$ such that $0\in G$, $1\in H$ and $G\cap H=\emptyset$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(G),f^{-1}(H)\subset X$ are open such that

$f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)=f^{-1}(G\cap H)=f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$,

$f(x)=0\in G \implies f(x)\in G \implies x\in f^{-1}(G)$,

$f(F)=\{1\}\subset H \implies f(F)\subset H \implies F\subset f^{-1}(H)$.

Thus, for every $x\in X$ and each minimal closed set $F\subset X$ such that $x\not\in F$, there exists open sets $f^{-1}(G),f^{-1}(H)\subset X$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(G)$, $F\subset f^{-1}(H)$ and $f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H)=\emptyset$. Hence, $X$ is min c-regular space.

---

Now, I want to clarify the sentence "**the space $[0,1]$ with relativised usual topology is Hausdorff.**"

Firstly, I need to know that what the usual topology on $[0,1]$ is.
I have tried to find the base of the usual topology on $[0,1]$ but...

$X=[0,1]$, $\tau=$ Standard Topology

If I consider that the base is $\beta=\{(a,b)\in X : 0<b<a<1\}$, then I cannot generate $[0,1]$.

Thank you for your helps..

Comment: *Usual topology* here refers to the usual topology on $\Bbb R$; it’s being relativised to $[0,1]$, so they’re talking about topology that $[0,1]$ inherits from $\Bbb R$. This has a base consisting of the intervals $(a,b)$ with $0\le a<b\le 1$, the intervals $[0,a)$ with $0<a\le 1$, and the intervals $(a,1]$ with $0\le a<1$.

Comment: How can we write exactly the base and the topology of this?

Comment: I wrote one base for it. Alternatively, since the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ is the topology induced by the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, the relative topology on $[0,1]$ is the topology induced by the same metric restricted to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. I think that you’re making this much harder than it really is: they’re just talking about the usual topology on $[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R$ with **its** usual topology.

Comment: So, it is the usual topology that we know, but the elements are not in (-, + infty). They are just restricted by [0,1].

Comment: Yes, it’s just the subspace topology, consisting of all sets $U\cap[0,1]$ such that $U$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Omg, thank you..

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that $[0,1]$ in the inherited topology from $\Bbb R$ (in the usual topology too) is Hausdorff. This is quite clear as that topology is metric (so Hausdorff), ordered (another reason it's Hausdorff) and hence so are all its subspaces as well as Hausdorff-ness is hereditary. No more than that.